# Python Lists within list

Tags: python

I have 1 master list which is based on 2 child lists. I want to create a function with "search_value" parameter & would like to print the index position of the "search_value" item including the list index of child list.

Example:

```
grocery = ["Juice", "Tomato", "Potato", "Banana", "Milk", "Bread"]
clothes = ["Shirt", "Pant", "Jacket", "Sweater", "Hat", "Pajama", "T-Shiraz", "Polo"]

master_list = [grocery, clothes]
```

Expected result :

```
"The Item You Searched For is", search_value, ". It is in the first/second list with index position of:", index #
```

I am new to python & have written the working code. Just want to know how to do it with less effort

```
def function(in_coming_string_to_search):

grocery = ["Juice", "Tomato", "Potato", "Banana", "Milk", "Bread"]
clothes = ["Shirt", "Pant", "Jacket", "Sweater", "Hat", "Pajama", "T-Shiraz", "Polo"]
master_list = [grocery, clothes]

length = int(len(master_list))
print master_list, "List has:", length, "list items", '\n'
to_do_list_first_array_index = 0
counter = 0
list_one_length = int(len(master_list[0]))

while counter < list_one_length:
    for a in master_list[to_do_list_first_array_index]:
        # print a
        if a == in_coming_string_to_search:
            print "The Item You Searched For is", in_coming_string_to_search, ". It is in the first list with index position of:", counter
        counter = counter + 1

to_do_list_second_array_index = 1
counter2 = 0
list_two_length = int(len(master_list[1]))

while counter2 < list_two_length:
    for b in master_list[to_do_list_second_array_index]:
        if b == in_coming_string_to_search:
            print "The Item You Searched For is", in_coming_string_to_search, ". It is in the second list with index position of:", counter2
        counter2 = counter2 + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
 string_to_search = "Tomato"
 function(string_to_search)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about (assuming `master_list` and its sub-lists are defined once and for all in global scope **before** this):

```
def search(needle):
    for i, sublist in enumerate(master_list):
        where = sublist.find(in_coming_string_to_search)
        if where == -1: continue
        print "The Item You Searched For is", needle
        print "It is in the {} sublist, at {}".format(nd(i), where)
        return
    print "Could not find {} anywhere".format(needle)

ordinals = "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth" 
def nd(i):
    if i<len(ordinals): return ordinals[i]
    return "{}th".format(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. I  am able to get the desired result with much less effort. Below is my final code. Hope you guys all will agree:

```
def two_dim_list(incoming_item_to_search):
    my_list = [["Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Grape", "Pear"], ["Book", "Pen", "Ink", "Paper", "Pencil"], ["Shirt", "Pant", "Jacket", "Hat", "Coat"]]

    list_length = len(my_list)
    counter = 0

    while counter < list_length:
        try:
            index = my_list[counter].index(incoming_item_to_search)
            if index >= 0:
                print "found item", incoming_item_to_search, "at index:", index, "of", counter,  "sublist"
        except ValueError:
            pass
        counter = counter + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    item_to_search = "Coat"
    two_dim_list(item_to_search)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be condensed considerably by making use of `enumerate` to iterate over sub-lists while keeping track of the index, and using the `.index` method of each sub-list:

```
def FindInLists( listOfLists, searchTerm ):
    for listIndex, subList in enumerate( listOfLists ):
        if searchTerm in subList:
            pos = subList.index( searchTerm )
            print( "{term} found at position {pos} of list #{which}".format( term=repr( searchTerm ), pos=pos, which=listIndex ) )
            return listIndex, pos
    print( "{term} not found".format( term=repr( searchTerm ) ) )
    return None, None


# test:

grocery = ["Juice", "Tomato", "Potato", "Banana", "Milk", "Bread"]
clothes = ["Shirt", "Pant", "Jacket", "Sweater", "Hat", "Pajama", "T-Shiraz", "Polo"]
master_list = [grocery, clothes]

print( FindInLists( master_list, "Hat" ) )
print( FindInLists( master_list, "Hats" ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `index` function, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/176918/584846):

```
try:
    index1 = master_list[0].index(in_coming_string_to_search)
    if index1 >= 0:
        print "The Item You Searched For is", in_coming_string_to_search, ". It is in the first list with index position of:", index1
except ValueError:
    pass

try:
    index2 = master_list[1].index(in_coming_string_to_search)
    if index2 >= 0:
        print "The Item You Searched For is", in_coming_string_to_search, ". It is in the secpnd list with index position of:", index2
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: `if index1` is the wrong way to go.  If the search term is found as the first element of the list,  then `index1=0` so the if conditional fails even though that indicates a successful match.  If the item is not in the list, then `index` throws an exception.

Comment: @jez you're right.  The answer has been edited to show `index1 >= 0` and `index2 >= 0`

Comment: now the condition will never fail:  `index1` is either `>=0` (term found), or control will never reach the `if` line because of a `ValueError` exception (term not found).

Comment: @jez added exception handling.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following function will help:

```
def func(new_string):
    grocery = ["Juice", "Tomato", "Potato", "Banana", "Milk", "Bread"]
    clothes = ["Shirt", "Pant", "Jacket", "Sweater", "Hat", "Pajama", "T-Shiraz", "Polo"]
    master_list = [grocery, clothes]

    child_list_num = 1
    counter = 0

    for child_list in master_list:
        for item in child_list:
            if item == new_string:
                print("The Item You Searched For is", new_string,
                      ". It is in the chlid list "+ str(child_list_num) +
                      " with index position of:", counter)
                return None
            counter += 1
        counter = 0
        child_list_num += 1

    print("The item does not exist.")
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    item = "Sweater"
    func(item)
```

If you want to print ALL the instances of the item, then remove the '`return None`' statement in the innermost loop, add a `found` value that is set to 1 whenever the first instance of the item is found  and the following statement at the end:

```
if (found == 0):
    print("The item does not exist.")
    return None
```

Comment: This answer of course assumes that being new to python, you might not have encountered other complex syntaxes of the language

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite hard to read and very redundant.

1. ****DO NOT**** use `function` as a function name, it's a built-in type
2. `length = int(len(master_list))` is repetitive, use `len(master_list)`, len will return a int, no need to convert it.
3. You should use for loops instead of while, and enumerator instead of a counter.
4. Your variable names are too long
5. Check your indentation too, they should be 4 spaces, you have mismatched of uses.
6. use string formatting ( the `%`) instead of printing with commas
7. Avoid long lines, max to 120 chars per line.
8. No need to put everything in new variables.

Here's the same code.

```
def find_string(target):
    master_list = [
        ["Juice", "Tomato", "Potato", "Banana", "Milk", "Bread"],
        ["Shirt", "Pant", "Jacket", "Sweater", "Hat", "Pajama", "T-Shiraz", "Polo"]
    ]

    print "Master List has %d sub-lists.\n" % len(master_list)
    print "The item you are searching for is '%s'." % target
    for list_index, sub_list in enumerate(master_list):
        for item_index, item in enumerate(sub_list):
            if item == target:
                print "\tFound at sub-list %d in index position %d" % (list_index+1, item_index)
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_string("Tomato")
```

Output:

```
Master List has 2 sub-lists.

The item you are searching for is 'Tomato'.
    Found at sub-list 1 in index position 1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Some observations:

You need to indent your code. While loops are usually not needed, especially for situations like this (i.e. you are simply trying to loop over a list to match an item).

Look at some of the functions I'm using here: For example, `format` will help clean the syntax being used when needing to express several variables inside a string. It is not necessary, but in certain situations this will be greatly beneficial.

Also look at `enumerate` to get the index of an item in addition to the item itself when using `for loops`.

Finally, take a look at PEP8 for some guidelines on style and formatting. Simple and short variable names are always best. As long as it still expresses the type of data clearly.

```
 # In Python, you need to indent the contents of the function
 # (the convention is 4 spaces)
def searchItem(searchString): # Avoid really long variable names.

    grocery = [
        "Juice", "Tomato", "Potato",
        "Banana", "Milk", "Bread"
    ]
    clothes = [
        "Shirt", "Pant", "Jacket", "Sweater",
        "Hat", "Pajama", "T-Shiraz", "Polo"
    ]

    masterDict = {'grocery': grocery, 'clothes': clothes}

    # No need to use int(). len() returns an int by default.
    length = len(masterDict)

    # Printing the master_list variable actually prints the list 
    # representation (and not the variable name), which is probably 
    # not what you wanted.
    print 'master_dict has a length of {0}'.format(length), '\n'

    itemInfo = None
    for listType, subList in masterDict.iteritems():
        for itemIndex, item in enumerate(subList):
            if item == searchString:
                itemInfo = {'listType': listType, 'itemIndex': itemIndex}
                break

    if itemInfo:
        print ("The item you searched for is {0}. It's in the {1} "
               "list with an index of {2}").format(
               searchString, itemInfo['listType'], itemInfo['itemIndex'])
    else:
        print ('The item you searched for ("{0}") was not found.'
              .format(searchString))
```

**Input**:

```
searchString = "Tomato"
searchItem(searchString)
```

**Output**:

```
"The item you searched for is Tomato. It's in the grocery list with an index of 1"
```

**Input**:

```
searchString = "banana"
searchItem(searchString)
```

**Output**:

```
'The item you searched for ("banana") was not found.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this will be:

```
grocery = ["Juice", "Tomato", "Potato", "Banana", "Milk", "Bread"]
clothes = ["Shirt", "Pant", "Jacket", "Sweater", "Hat", "Pajama", "T-Shiraz", "Polo"]

master_list = [grocery, clothes]

def search(needle):
    return_string = "The item you searched for is {}. It is in the {}{} list with index position of {}"
    ordinals = {"1":"st", "2":"nd", "3":"rd"}
    for lst_idx,sublst in enumerate(master_list, start=1):
        try:
            needle_idx = str(sublst.index(needle))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            lst_idx = str(lst_idx)
            return return_string.format(needle,
                                        lst_idx,
                                        ordinals.get(lst_idx, 'th'),
                                        needle_idx)
    return "The item {} is not in any list.".format(needle)
```

DEMO

```
In [11]: search("Juice")
Out[11]: 'The item you searched for is Juice. It is in the 1st list with index p
osition of 0'

In [12]: search("Pajama")
Out[12]: 'The item you searched for is Pajama. It is in the 2nd list with index
position of 5'

In [13]: search("Not existent")
Out[13]: 'The item Not existent is not in any list.'
```